# Correction about my code SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
      If($txtLastName != "") $txtAcceptanceDate1 = "" && $txtAcceptanceDate2 = ""
```

that is my code in my php...

im not really an expert but I have some knowlegde

I just want to make The input on $txtAcceptanceDate1 and $txtAcceptanceDate2 to become empty if $txtLastName is not empty

Comment: $txtAcceptanceDate1 = "";$txtAcceptanceDate2 = "";

Comment: its that sql ? or just php ?

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
if(!empty($txtLastName))
{
$txtAcceptanceDate1="";
$txtAcceptanceDate2 ="";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if( trim($txtLastName) != "") {
    $txtAcceptanceDate1 = "";
    $txtAcceptanceDate2 = "";
}
```

`trim` is a php function to clear all the empty spaces

Answer (score 0):

```
If(!empty($txtLastName)) {
  $txtAcceptanceDate1 = "";
  $txtAcceptanceDate2 = "";
}
```

Please go and read manual for such questions: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php